# Random Number Minecraft

Tags: java, random, int, minecraft, bukkit

Im trying to set a random number but excluding a certain number in the random.

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {

    Player player = (Player) sender;

    if(commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("random")){

        Random random = new Random();
        int randomId = random.nextInt(300);

        if(randomId >= 100 && randomId <= 200){
            player.sendMessage("" + randomId);
        }

        while(randomId != 124){
            randomId = random.nextInt(300);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to EXCLUDE the number 124 in the random.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work ? Replace `random.nextInt(300)` with `random.nextInt(200)` and `while(randomId != 124)` with `while(randomId == 124)`.

Comment: If you want a number between 100 and 200, why do you start by generating a number between 0 and 299? Do you want to do nothing 2/3 of the time?

Comment: I just want to generate a number between two values, Example: 0 and 299 but i dont want the random number to be 124

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get it like so:

```java
Random r = new Random();

int generated = r.nextInt(299); // generate 0..299
if(generated >= 124) {
    generated++; // skip 124
}
// now you can send the number
```

Note that this doesn't involve any loops, and will always skip 124 to give value in range [0..300)

Comment: This will add a bias to number 125.

Comment: I don't think it will bias the 125, as the entire number space is shifted. It would be a problem if the condition checked only for equality, as in `generated == 124`.

Comment: Nice necro ;-). I don't know what I was thinking when I made that comment. You're right Sebi, it is not biased.

Answer (score 1):

You're looping until the number is 124. "While !" means "Until"

You're also sending the message *before* doing your loop.

What you really want is:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
    final Player player = (Player) sender;

    if (commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("random")) {

        final Random random = new Random();
        int randomId;

        do {
            randomId = random.nextInt(300);
        } while (randomId == 124);

        if (randomId >= 100 && randomId <= 200) {
            player.sendMessage(String.valueOf(randomId));
        }
    }
```